# Can't get a drop-down item's ID

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to get the id of the selected item in my PHP-generated drop down. Right now the console says "Uncaught TypeError: Object #exchanges option:selected has no method 'attr'" I can't figure out what's going wrong.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Administration</title>
    <style>
        #exchanges {
            width: 300px;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="http://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <?php populateDropDown(); ?>
    <button id="display_button">Display Information</button>
</body>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#display_button').on('click', function(){
            var dropdown_id = ('#exchanges option:selected').attr('id');
            alert(dropdown_id); // doesn't work
        });
    });


</script>

</html>
```

PHP function:

```
function populateDropDown(){
$conn = connectPDO();

echo '<select id="exchanges">';

foreach($conn->query('SELECT * FROM exchange') as $row) {
    echo '<option id ='.$row['exchangeID'].'>'; 
    echo $row['exchange-name'];
    echo '</option>';
    }

echo '</select>';

}
```

Comment: The select menu itself can utilize that methodology, but its children (options) can not.
The default behavior is for that form element to return ITs selected value, not its child's ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you forgot dollar sign in your jQuery code:

```
var dropdown_id = ('#exchanges option:selected').attr('id');
```

should be:

```
var dropdown_id = $('#exchanges option:selected').attr('id');
```

Also, in your PHP, change this:

```
echo '<option id ='.$row['exchangeID'].'>';
```

to the following:

```
echo '<option id="'.$row['exchangeID'].'">';
```

And see if it works now.

Comment: Jeeze. Not sure how I missed that. Works now, thanks!!! Will mark correct once the time elapse ends.